# Почему папка "android" весит 22.5Gb?

Tags: windows, android-studio

Изначально, я полагаю, эта папка столько не весила, чем заполнилась? Обновления не делал, а только компилировал тестовые игры на андроид под Unity, используя "SDK" ). Вообще, эту "андроид студио" скачивал из-за того, что нужен был "SDK" для сборки игры на андроид. А теперь, плюс к этим 22гб могут прибавиться несколько гб, ведь новая версия Unity требует новых версий "SDK". Подытоживая, как поступить: полностью всё это дело с папкой андроид снести и скачать заново то, что нужно или обновится? И чем была заполнена эта папка?

Comment: Это папка, созданная при установке андроид студио, если что

Comment: Посмотрите, скорее всего у вас туда докачивается SDK (+ немного кэша от студии). Самый простой вариант - поменять в настройках местоположение SDK (и перенести саму директорию)

Comment: Не воспроизводится. У меня точно такая же папка и она не весит 22 гига :p Эмуляторы использовал? Сколько версий сдк установлено?

Comment: я думаю что поставлено очень много версий sdk и как результат все раздуто) соглашусь с @Jarvis_J что нужно просто перенести эту директорию и поменять ее местоположение. У меня папка весит 1.6 гб и сдк весит 8.6гб. таких чисел ооочень сложно добиться

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796230/android-sdk-folder-taking-a-lot-of-disk-space-do-we-need-to-keep-all-of-the-sys

Comment: Спасибо ответившим. Решил снести всю папку и заново скачать, ибо по времени выиграю, чем всё перебирать.

Comment: В моём случае было 4 Виртуальных образа для эмуляции Android, занимали 16 Gb.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что может быть:

1. Виртуальные образы для эмуляции Android
2. 3D Studio
3. MinGW
4. Python и другие языки, требующие компиляторы
5. Сама IDE не легкая (весит около 6 гигаметров)
6. Кэш
7. Unity жрет до 50 гигов под кэш

8. Мусор